# Alternative for subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, subquery

I have this query that has subquery in the FROM clause

```
SELECT x, y 
FROM FOO 
WHERE y IN (SELECT y 
            FROM 
                (SELECT y, z, MIN(v)  
                 FROM BAR 
                 GROUP BY y, z))
```

The professor teaching the class said that not all databases support it and I should only use subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.

I'm trying to convert the query above not to use a subquery in the `FROM` clause but can't figure this out.

Any idea ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Not all databases?!? In 2020 all do.

Comment: But you don't need to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below -

```
Select distinct FOO.x,FOO.y 
  FROM FOO 
  JOIN ( SELECT y,z, min(v)  FROM  BAR groupby y,z) TAB 
  ON FOO.y = TAB.y;
```

I agree with the other comment from Gordon that the aggregation is quite unnecessary. However, I have kept close to what you tried in my response and still give the correct results while eliminating the extra sub-query using Join.

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

All databases support subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

As written, the aggregation is totally unnecessary.  You are comparing `y` values.  The calculation on `v` is irrelevant.  So, you might as well write:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM FOO
WHERE y in (SELECT y FROM BAR)
```

Comment: Edited the question - now the aggregation is needed I think

Comment: I think Gordon is still correct - as the processing for the `WHERE y in (some list of y values)` is only used to determine if y actually exists in BAR. Therefore you don't need the rest (z, MIN(v), group by). To check this, please try to find any dataset where it will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First, the sub-query:

```
SELECT y FROM ( SELECT y,z min(v)  FROM  BAR groupby y,z)
```

aside from missing a comma after `z` and a space between `group` and `by`, is equivalent to:

```
SELECT y from (SELECT DISTINCT y, z FROM BAR) sq1
```

which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT y from (SELECT DISTINCT y FROM BAR) sq1
```

which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT y FROM BAR
```

So:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM FOO
WHERE y in (
    SELECT DISTINCT y FROM BAR
)
```